# Do these imply the function is Analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x,y) : U \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $ \partial f/ \partial y$ and $ \partial f/ \partial x$ are continuous and $\forall c \in U$. Let $ S_c$ = circle centered at $c$ lying inside $U$ and $ \oint_{S_c} f = 0 $

Does this imply $f$ is analytic?

Comment: Is a Morera-type theorem. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42098/morera-type-theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the partial derivatives are continuous, $f$ is differentiable, that is,
$$ f(x,y) = f(x_0,y_0) + (x-x_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) + i(y-y_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) + o(|x-x_0| + |y-y_0|) .$$
So compute $\oint_{S_c} f$ where $c = x_0 + iy_0$ using polar coordinates:
$$ 0 = \oint_{S_c} f = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x_0+r\cos(\theta),y_0+r\sin(\theta)) \cdot(r (-\sin(\theta)+i\cos(\theta)) \, d\theta \\= r \pi i \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right) + o(r) .$$
Hence dividing by $r$ and letting $r \to 0$, we obtain
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) = 0 ,$$
that is, the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied.

Comment: I might have a sign error in the C-R conditions, and maybe my evaluation of the integral needs to be multiplied by $r$.  But I think the idea is correct.