# Morera's Theorem given in lectures

Tags: complex-analysis

In my lectures, Morera's Theorem was stated as follows:

> Suppose that $\Omega$ is a domain, that the function
>   $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous, and that $$\int_A f(z)dz=\int_B
>  f(z)dz,$$ whenever the **simple** contours $A$ and $B$, in $\Omega$, have the same
>   initial point and the same end point. Then $f$ in analytic on
>   $\Omega$.

A simple contour is one which does not cross itself. However, I feel as though the simple contour condition is superfluous. Here is my reasoning:

Suppose $A,B$ are simple contours with the start and end points $z,w$, respectively. Also, $C,D$ are simple contours with the start and end points $w,z'$, respectively. Denote $A\cup C$ and $B\cup D$ to be the joins of $A$ and $C$, and $B$ and $D$, respectively. If we have

1. $\int_A f(z)dz = \int_B f(z)dz$;
2. $\int_C f(z)dz = \int_D f(z)dz$,

then we clearly have
$$ \int_{A\cup C} f(z)dz =\int_A f(z)dz + \int_C f(z)dz = \int_B f(z)dz + \int_D f(z)dz = \int_{B\cup D} f(z)dz,$$
where $A\cup C$ and $B\cup D$ are both non-simple contours. Am I correct in feeling that the condition is superfluous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you are asking about is one of the conditions of the theorem, not one of its consequences. Having a weaker condition is actually *better* here, in that you have to check fewer contours in order to prove that your function is analytic. Indeed, you can [apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42098/morera-type-theorems?rq=1) weaken the assumption to translations and scalings of any one fixed-shape contour you like.

As far as actually answering your question goes: a non-simple closed curve can be very complicated, and separating it into simple parts is not so straightforward as you might hope: you can cook up curves that cross themselves infinitely many times, and all sorts of horrors like that. (I'm not sure if you can make an uncountable number of crossings, but I'm sure someone's had a go...) Therefore I would say that, given sufficient regularity, your proof is correct, but perhaps not in complete generality.