# Showing that if $\int_C f(z) \, dz=0$ for every circle $C$ in $\mathbb{C}$, then $f$ is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I understand that this is the difficult direction of Morera's proof, applied to disks, rather than triangles.

However, the trick of defining 
$$F(z)=\int_{\gamma(t)}f(w)\,dw, \text{ with } \gamma(t)=tz+(1-t)z_0$$

No longer works, as this function is no longer path invariant and therefore not well defined, although the particulars of this are not completely clear to me. Should I think of this definition of $F$ to be on cosets of 
$\mathbb{C}$ quotiented by paths in some way?

Any tips on how to approach this proof would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's a nice, short proof here: http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/v.caudrelier/Complex_variable/Handouts/H4.pdf

Comment: @Joanpemo That requires that the integral over any (simple) closed contour vanishes. Here it's only assumed that the integral over ever circle vanishes.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, I didn't notice that. I wonder how restrictive that really is...

Comment: also I should have added this question, but the set being simply connected seems crucial. If we replace $\mathbb{C}$ with an arbitrary set $U$, there is no guarantee that it is connected and I think the conclusion may be false

Comment: This looks related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42098/morera-type-theorems

Comment: yes I missed the hint, I am going to try and prove it the second way, will post solution if I get it

Comment: This is an ambiguity that mathematicians tolerate too much: "if $\int_C f(z) \, dz=0$ for any circle $C$ in $\mathbb{C}$, then${}\,\ldots$" could mean either of two things: "if there is any circle $C$ in $\mathbb{C}$ for which $\int_C f(z) \, dz=0,$ then${}\,\ldots$" or "if it is true that for any circle $C$ in $\mathbb{C}$, no matter which one, we have $\int_C f(z) \, dz=0,$ then$\,{}\ldots$".  Just saying "every" instead of "any" would be unambiguous and would have the second meaning and not the first. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy edited, although I side more with wittgenstein on these things

Comment: @qbert : What does Wittgenstein say about this? $\qquad$

Comment: just the idea that a word is defined by its use; if mathematicians all use "any" to mean "for any arbitrary" or "for every" then that is the meaning

Comment: @qbert : But the word "any" is used in different ways.  In negative and interogative sentences especially, "any" is close to "some" than to "every", as in "There isn't any matrix that is blahblahblah." $\qquad$